# Pipe the stream between stdin and stdout

Tags: node.js, nodejs-stream

We can echo line by line on *nodejs* via [stream pipe](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) from *stdin* to *stdout*, i.e. from *Readable* to *Writable* stream:

```
process.stdin.pipe(process.stdout);
```

Confusingly, it also works same as before from *stdout* to *stdin*, i.e. from *Writable* to *Readable* stream below. Why?

```
process.stdout.pipe(process.stdin);
```

**@EDIT**

The similar test with [io.Copy](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) in *golang* has reproduced the aforementioned issue. The cross-validation seems to hint the builtin *pipe* implementation can't be wrong on both incumbent platforms.

```
 package main                                                                                                          

 import (                                                                                                              
     "io"                                                                                                              
     "os"                                                                                                              
 )                                                                                                                     

 func main() {                                                                                                         
     io.Copy(os.Stdout, os.Stdin)                                                                                      
     // io.Copy(os.Stdin, os.Stdout) /* Also works than expected. */                                                                
 }
```

**@EDIT 2**

For further investigation another test with [Deno.copy](https://doc.deno.land/https/github.com/denoland/deno/releases/latest/download/lib.deno.d.ts#Deno.copy) on the third platform *deno* behaves as expected:

```
Deno.copy(Deno.stdout, Deno.stdin); /* Works as expected. */
// Deno.copy(Deno.stdin, Deno.stdout); /* Fails as expected. */
```

Comment: The second one doesn't seem to work for me.  I get an `ENOTCONN` error.

Comment: I even tested with the similar function [io.Copy](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) in *golang* by exchanging *src dst* pair between *os.Stdin os.Stdout* - the effect doesn't vary.

Comment: What does that comment mean and why are you talking about golang in a node.js question?  I cannot reproduce what you say in your question in node.js.   `process.stdout.pipe(process.stdin);` produces nothing but an error for me.

Comment: It cross-validates that the builtin *pipe* implementation can't be wrong on both *nodejs* and *golang*, even I didn't get the error you did.

Comment: What version of node.js are you running?  I'm running v12.13.1.

Comment: Current LTS v12.16.2